# iOS PJSIP library not found when using AWS library with cocoa pods

Tags: ios, xcode, aws-sdk, pjsip

When i install AWS SDK in my xcode project, the reference of PJSIP libraries removed automatically. Below error comes over on console:

> -library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9

What could be the issue or workaround!!